# Apply for UK Residence Card for non EEA family member of an EEA national

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family, eu-spouses

My wife has joined me in UK (I am an EEA National), after applying for EEA Family permit, she being a Non EEA national. She has 6 months of validity for her EEA Family Permit.

And I want to apply for her residence card, but not sure when to apply.

Is it possible to apply now? My wife has arrived in UK less than a month ago.

Or shall I wait for expiry of the EEA Family Permit? Or may be apply 1-2 months before the expiry date of EEA Family Permit?

Comment: It can take up to 6 months for an application of be successful or get denied.

Comment: @abubakkarrangara if you don't mind me asking did you apply for the residence cars through a lawyer or did you do it your self. Thank-you

Comment: @abubakkarrangara if you don't mind me asking did you apply for the residence cars through a lawyer or did you do it your self. Thank-you

Comment: @Maciej did it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter when when your wife applies for the residence card, because the residence card is not mandatory:

> You don’t need to apply for a residence card as a family member ...

(https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/overview)

She probably wants the card anyway, of course, because among other things it will document her right to work and to enter the UK if she travels internationally.

If she is concerned about having a gap between the expiration of the EEA family permit and the receipt of the residence card, then she should apply as soon as possible.  On the other hand, if she'd rather delay the expense associated with the application, she can do so.  I do not know how long a residence card application is likely to take, but if you can find out, you and your wife will be able to decide for yourselves whether it makes sense to delay the submission of her application.

(The decision on when to apply may also depend on your own status, since you must be able to prove that you are a "qualified person."  You've probably already done that, since she has an EEA family permit.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to apply 1-2 month before the expire date of EEU family permit as it may take some time to process and approve your new permit.